# How to make a maven project buildable for the customer

Tags: maven-2, maven, nexus

We have a project which should be buildable by the customer using maven. It has some open source dependencies that are mavenized (no problem), some that aren't mavenized, proprietary stuff (oracle jdbc driver) and some internal stuff.

Until now we had everything but the first category packaged with the project itself in a local repository (repository with file://path-in-project-folder specified in the projects pom.xml).

We would love to move these out of the project, as we are about to use them in other projects as well. Currently we plan to use nexus as an internal maven repository.

Whats the best practice to make such dependencies/maven repositories available to the customer so he can continue to build the project.

Ideas so far:

- Customer sets up a nexus repository as well, we somehow deploy all these non-public dependencies to his repository (like a mirror)
- We provide a 'dumb' dump/snapshot of the non-public dependencies, customer adds this snapshot to this settings.xml as a repository, (but how is this possible).
- Make our internal nexus repo available to the customers build server (not an option in our case)

I'm wondering how others solve these problems.

Thank you!

Comment: Give the customer an account on your local hudson/jenkins is out of question?

Comment: Yep unfortunately it is , different networks, and their network policy is even stricter than ours. Plus they add some internal/specific things to the build (mainly specific configuration)... but thats another story.

Comment: It's quite easy to copy artifacts or even your entire ~/.m2/repository and provide it to another developer or a repository manager.  The much harder issue is dealing with the licensing restrictions of each artifact.  Some licenses restrict redistribution even if the artifact is free of cost {insert grumble at Sun here.}  I tend to go out of my way to find an artifact in a public repository rather than go to the trouble of managing all the developer's local repositories or our company one (which is encumbered by red tape.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, hosting a repository of some kind is a straightforward option, as long as you can cover the uptime / bandwidth / authentication requirements.

If you're looking to ship physical artifacts, you'll find this pattern helpful: https://brettporter.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/a-maven-friendly-pattern-for-storing-dependencies-in-version-control/

That relies on the repository being created in source control - if you want a project to build a repository, consider something like: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/npanday/trunk/dist/npanday-repository-builder/pom.xml?revision=1139488&view=markup (using the assembly plugin's capability to build a repository).

Basically, by building a repository you can ship that with the source code and use file:// to reference it from within the build.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Document exactly what artifacts you need to compile which are not
   available via Maven Central
2. Implement Nexus and make a export with Nexus give the export 
   to customer and they need to do a import of it. I'm not sure 
   if you come to licenses issues.

I assumed that you already have a Repository Manager already but it reads like you didn't.